# Recover boolean vector from dot products

Tags: machine-learning, combinatorics, linear-algebra, subset-sum

**Question:**

I want to determine a boolean vector $b \in \{0,1\}^n$ consisting of zeros and ones, but cannot access it directly. I can only call a black-box computer code which will take the dot product of $b$ with a real-valued vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ of my choosing. I.e., access to $b$ is available through evaluation of the map
$$v \mapsto b^T v.$$
How can I recover all of the entries of $b$ using as few of these dot products as possible? (maybe even just 1 dot product?)

Below I detail a couple ideas I had which might work in theory, but which don't work in practice (I think). For concreteness, one may assume that $n \approx 1 \text{ million}$, and arithmetic is done in double precision floating point format. This question arose as a subproblem in a machine learning application.

---

**Idea 1:**

One idea I had is to use a vector with fast growing entries. Say, for example, $n=9$. Then we could use the vector 
$$v=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 10 & 100 & 1000 & \dots\end{bmatrix}^T.$$
One could then read off $b$ as the digits of $b^T v$. The problem with this solution is that the numbers grow so fast, that in finite precision computer arithmetic it will not work for large $n$.

---

**Idea 2:**

Another idea I had was to use a vector with entries that are algebraically independent. Then determining $b$ from $b^Tv$ is a subset sum problem.

For example, if $n=3$ and
$$v = \begin{bmatrix}\pi & e & 1\end{bmatrix}^T,$$
then $b^T v$ will take on one of a finite number of possibilities,
$$b^T v \in \{\pi,~e,~1,~\pi+e,~\pi+1,~e+1,~\pi+e+1\}.$$
We can determine which of these is the case, thereby determining $b$.

But this seems quite combinatorial, and therefore unfeasible for large $n$.

Comment: "$b^T v \in \{\pi,~e,~1,~\pi+e,~\pi+1,~e+1,~\pi+e+1\}$". 0 is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an variant of the idea 1 in the question, where a factor of 2 is used to replace the original factor of 9.

1. Let $v=[2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, \cdots, 2^{62}, 2^{63}, 0, 0, 0, \cdots]^T$. Obtain $b^Tv$, which will determine the first 64 entries of $b$.
2. Let $v=[0, 0, 0, \cdots, (64 \text { zeros}),  1, 2, 2^2, 2^3, \cdots, 2^{62}, 2^{63}, 0, 0, 0, \cdots]^T$. Obtain $b^Tv$, which will determine the next 64 entries of $b$.
3. Let $v=[0, 0, 0, \cdots, (128 \text { zeros}),  1, 2, 2^2, 2^3, \cdots, 2^{62}, 2^{63}, 0, 0, 0, \cdots]^T$. Obtain $b^Tv$, which will determine the next 128 entries of $b$.
4. And so on, until we have determined all entries of $b$. There may be less than 64 positive numbers in $v$ in the last round.

The above scheme is the best possible if the number of effective bits in $b^Tv$ is 64 and we have no prior knowledge about $v$ except the number of its entries. This can be seen easily from information theory, as each query against the black box can provide at most 64 bits of information.

Comment: Oh, I see. This makes sense, thank you